# Repaint() cannot make a static reference to a non static method?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, paint, repaint

am having trouble with some code which I have been writing. I am trying to change from Main to a paintComponent method, but it says cannot make a static reference to a non-static method. I think I understand what it is saying, but I am unsure how to get around this. The class is as below:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Main extends JFrame{       
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4511248732627763442L;

    public static void main(String[] args){     

        frame();        
        repaint();      
        move();         
    }

    public static void frame(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hunter VS Hunted");          
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);          
        frame.setVisible(true);                             
        frame.setResizable(false);                          
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponents(g);   
        Hunter.paint(g);            
        Hunted.paint(g);            


    }

    public static void move(){

        Hunter.move();          
        Hunted.move();                      

    }
}
```

Hunter and hunted in this class are two external classes. The error is occurring in the main method, on repaint() and any advice/direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your `repaint()` method is an instance method - so it needs to be called on an instance. Which instance do you want to call it on? You're not actually *creating* any instances at the moment...

Comment: `repaint` is an instance method `JFrame`, you need an instance of the class in order to call the method.  Additionally, you are extending from `JFrame`, but creating a second `JFrame` in the (`static`?) `frame` method, so even if you were able to call `repaint` on `Main`, it would have no effect.  Stop making things `static` - (over use/relience on) `static` in a GUIs == bad design

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the same is in Component class, repaint method is a non static method. You may want to do something like:

```
Main myMain = new Main();
myMain.repaint();
```

or if you intent to use it on jframe that you create from frame method then you could do like:

```
public static JFrame frame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hunter VS Hunted");          
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);          
    frame.setVisible(true);                             
    frame.setResizable(false);                          
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    return frame;
}
```

and in your main method you could do like:

```
 JFrame frame = frame();
 frame.repaint();
```

Comment: The OP extends from `JFrame`, but is creating another `JFrame` internally, so calling `repaint` on `Main` is unlikely to have any affect

Comment: Yes i think user is intending to use frame that he created from frame that he creates before calling repaint method and use it may be in some other class as well.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create the frame, and then draw objects on top of the created frame in the two separate classes, but that requires moving graphics g right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between static methods and instance methods.

Static methods are there to do things that are not related to the state of a particular object. They can create new object, run operations on their given parameters, or manipulate static fields.

However, these exist just in the class and are not related to any particular object.

To work with swing, you create actual objects - different panels, buttons, and other components. Each of them is an object, and there can be many objects of the same class (many `Button`s, many `Frames`). The state of each object determines how it will behave. One button, when pressed, will do one thing, and another will do another thing. One has this color, the other has that color, etc.

So behavior like `repaint()` or even setting an action listener is not a behavior that applies to the whole class, just to one specific object, button, panel etc.

Thus, your `Hunted` and `Hunter` classes' behavior should be created with the view of a specific instance created with `hunter = new Hunter(...)` and `hunted = new Hunted()`, and their methods should be called with the references to the objects, not directly from the class, because these methods relate to the state of a particular object, which is being drawn on the screen etc.

I'm not sure you even want Main to be a JFrame. But if you do, you have to create a `new Main()` and add whatever components to it. Not just create some JFrame and then expect the `paintComponent()` method to apply to it, because you wrote it as a method of Main().

You probably just want to create a JFrame and add two components, a Hunter (created with `new Hunter()`) and a Hunted (created with `new Hunted()`) to it, and consider how each of these components relates to each other, when you write their (non static!) methods.